# Split a vertically window

Tags: window-management

Can we split a vertical window in two equally parts?
Something like:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to use [QuickTile](https://github.com/ssokolow/quicktile) for this kind of thing.

afaik eOS doesn't have native support for this. There's a bounty for it [here](https://www.bountysource.com/issues/931574-gala-should-support-better-window-tiling), as well.

Comment: Sadly this feature request is quite old, so think about adding a bounty ;)